# Android MediaCodec AVC / H264 generates invalid keyframe and codec config

Tags: android, video, h.264

I've setup MediaCodec to encode frames using AVC but I can't quite seem to understand why it is giving me a short CODEC_CONFIG and a really weird first frame.

00 00 00 01 65 b8 40 7f ff f0 f4 50 00 10 7d f7 0f 5f 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d f7 df 7d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d5 57 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 5d 75 d7 80

Its alternating 5d and d7

The CODEC_CONFIG is also shorter than normal and doesn't seem to make sense.

00 00 00 01 67 42 c0 1e e9 01 40 7b 40 3c 22 11 a8 00 00 00 01 68 ce 06 e2

The frames after this are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two types of NAL formats.  Stream and Packetized.  The GPU creates a Stream NAL.  Most network protocols such as RTP etc all require the Packetized format.  The Packetized Decoder Configuration is found in ISO 14496-15 under AVCDecoderConfigurationRecord.  You can find the Stream NAL in ISO 14496-10.

You actually have to parse out chunks of the Stream NAL and convert it to the Packetized.  SPS/PPS NALs are a little more involved.  IDR etc NALs can be done by simply replacing the 00 00 00 01 bytes with your length parameter as defined in the SPS.

Comment: Can you share any more information about converting Stream NAL to Packetized Decoder Configuration? Trying to write mpegts from MediaCodec output with FFmpeg. I don't have the $200+ USD to buy access to ISO 14496-15 :( http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=55980

Comment: Thanks! Also: http://ubuntuone.com/2Da0iaDt28vguB6OAoADyf seems to be a freely hosted 2004 edition of the spec. The current edition is 2010, but it's still been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Every thing seems ok without running it through the parser.

However the paste bin is telling.

The AVC codec packet is defiantly questionable, I think.

17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 67 42 c0 0d e9 02 83 f4 03 c2 21 1a 80 00 00 00 01 68 ce 06 e2

The following tag as well

17 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 65 b8 40

And finally the interframe

27 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 41 e2 20.....

When going from annex B to FLV, you'll need to convert zero-byte markers to size markers. You also need to write the codec config how flash wants it. Refer to Red5 codecs for this. Inside the codec config, is specified how many bytes you are using for the size marker. its a 2 bit val+1 I think.

SHort answer... Trust the codec config.. Trust the frame output.. and try playback in flash again. Replace '0001' for size of payload. You had the correct 3 bytes presentation time, but you kept the 0001, and you might not be setting the size of your 'size specifier' in the header.

[2  Header][ 3 Presentaion-offset][ 2-4 size]payload [size]

The config building can be seen here.  http://code.google.com/p/comserver/source/browse/trunk/plugins/shoutcast/src/org/red5/server/plugin/shoutcast/marshal/transpose/VideoFramer.java#447